# UNUserNotificationCenter not clean notification of icon app in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11, xcode9

I have a problem. I had a notification in my app. Im trying this. But now, i can't delete from the icon app.

I run this code:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: {requests -> () in
            print("\(requests.count) requests -------")
            for request in requests{
                print(request.identifier)
            }

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        })

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: {deliveredNotifications -> () in
            print("\(deliveredNotifications.count) Delivered notifications-------")
            for notification in deliveredNotifications{
                print(notification.request.identifier)
            }

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        })
```

And trace is this:

0 requests -------
0 Delivered notifications-------

In the icon app, i see this:

[Im can't up image :( but in this, i see a number one on the icon app and red foreground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wgoo.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yayo you need to set badge count to `0` for removing badge count from your app icon. For that -

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```